# How i can edit the normal map node through python?

Tags: python, scripting, normal-map

I've a large scene with a lot of materials and I need to change the normal space and strength for all the materials, so how can i change them through python?

i've tried to run this code

```
import bpy

## list of all materials with nodes... because there might be those without
mats = [m for m in bpy.data.materials if m.use_nodes]

print("mats: ") ## print appropriate mat names into System Console (for debugging purposes)
for m in mats:
   for n in m.node_tree.nodes:
       ## if node type is Normal Map
       if n.type == 'NORMAL_MAP':
           print(m.name)
           n.inputs["Strength"].default_value = 1
```

And it works but i need to change the normal space too

Comment: `n.space = 'TANGENT'`. See [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeNormalMap.html#bpy.types.ShaderNodeNormalMap.space).